# UIView transitionWithView & setting the frame no longer works iOS8

Tags: uiview, ios8, uiviewanimation

Since updating to iOS8 many animations have stopped working. It appears that the `y` position of the view cannot be changed. In iOS7 there was no problem. But with iOS8 it will not go past the original `y` position.It appears that the frame of the view are indeed being updated but the frame is not being redrawn. Here is my code

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

self.table.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.bounds.size.height - self.button.frame.size.height) - (252), self.view.bounds.size.width, self.table.frame.size.height);


} completion:nil];
```

I have also tried this code outside of the animation block;

```
  self.table.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.bounds.size.height - self.button.frame.size.height) - (252), self.view.bounds.size.width, self.table.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** The solution is to adjust the auto layout constraints and not the `frames` origin. Click on the auto layout constraint you would like to adjust (in interface builder e.g top constraint). Next make this an `IBOutlet`;

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;
```

Then to animate it;

```
 self.topConstraint.constant = -100;
[self.viewToAnimate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];  
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [self.viewToAnimate layoutIfNeeded]; 
    }];
```

The above code will move the view/ or move the constraints upwards. To move it backdown to its original simply call;

```
  self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
[self.viewToAnimate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [self.viewToAnimate layoutIfNeeded]; 
    }];
```

**Second Solution**
I found the solution. It appears that if `self.table` is an `IBOutlet` then the animation wont work. I am guessing this a result of the new dynamic storyboards. Creating your elements all in code and not in the storyboard leads to a successful animation. That is all I had to do to get it to work, create the `UITableView` in code.

Comment: If anyone is also stuck with this, then don't use [self.viewToAnimate layoutSubviews]; inside animations block as it is not working. Use [self.viewToAnimate layoutIfNeeded]; instead.

Comment: @Borzh thats what the original answer says?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to emphasize that layoutIfNeeded method is needed and not layoutSubviews. The problem is that layoutSubviews is working on iOS 7.1 but not on iOS 8+